# Why do we have different formula of EMF induced due to a rotating pedal and a falling metallic rod

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I in my textbook while solving problems on emf induced due to change in flux discovered two different formulae for two situations at first place it was a rotating pedal with a few metallic spokes in and second was a Falling metallic rod and different approaches were used to solve questions as in the picture.
I was not kinda sure as if why were the formulae different.
[image: Emf induced due to rotating pedal and a falling metallic rod]

Comment: The $\frac v2 $ for the pedal is the average speed of the pedal ie not all parts of the pedal are travelling at the same speed.